# tensorflow comparing each element of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, compare

My input Tensor has size of `3x5`. 
I tried to get the total number of each tensor with values more than 1.
For example:

```
input list[[0.1 , 1.1 , 1.3, 1.5 , 0.7] ,
           [1.1 , 1.1 , 0.8, 1.5 , 0.7] ,
           [0.1 , 0.0 , 1.3, 0.5 , 1.7]]  
return[[3],[3],[2]]
```

because in the lists, there are 3 , 3 , 2 numbers having values greater than 1.

I originally hope to use the code below to solve it,

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.greater(inputs , one),one,zero),1)
```

'one' is a Tensor with the size of `3x5`, and all values are 1. 'zero' is a Tensor with the size of `3x5`, with all values zero.
But I then realize that tf.greater cannot be used this way. Is there any recommended code for solving my problem? I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while and haven't found a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This returns

> [3 3 2]

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputlist = [[0.1 , 1.1 , 1.3, 1.5 , 0.7] ,
           [1.1 , 1.1 , 0.8, 1.5 , 0.7] ,
           [0.1 , 0.0 , 1.3, 0.5 , 1.7]]

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=inputlist)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print( sess.run( tf.count_nonzero(( tf.greater(inputlist, tf.constant(1.0)) ), 1)) )
```